# easy way to escape special characters in a text field

Tags: postgresql, go, special-characters

I am trying to use copy in golang to load hundreds of thousands of lines of texts files in a postgres database. Sometimes it fails because lines have special characters (non ascii). If I replace non ascii chars it works fine.

Is there a simple/easy way to save not allowed characters in a text field or another kind of field? Or a postgres function that valid a text to avoid a transaction with wrong characters?

Comment: Maybe you could add some additional context. At what point does it fail, what is the failure (error message)? How do you insert into the DB, e.g. do you create an SQL statement by string concatenation, are you using a prepared statement? What type of column and encoding do you insert into? Which "not allowed characters" specifically?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports suggests there's an API available designed for this purpose.  I.e. handling escaping automatically and using `COPY` behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using db.Exec().

```
col1Val := `string 1 with special characters`
col2Val := `string 2 with special characters`
sqlStr := `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2)`
_, err = db.Exec(sqlStr, col1Val, col2Val)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

db.Exec escapes special characters by itself and removes SQL injections.

Comment: I am using copy for performance reasons: https://medium.com/@amoghagarwal/insert-optimisations-in-golang-26884b183b35 (approach 2)

Comment: You can use fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('%s', '%s');", col1Val, col2Val). But this is not a good idea because of sql injections. And again, fmt.Sprintf will kill all the performance gains.